# How to properly release the memory used by a pipeline?

Tags: gstreamer

I am developing a program that need to create and delete a pipeline several times, but memory grows every time I do this.

How to properly release the memory used by a pipeline?

I am using GStreamer 1.12.2 and Ubuntu 14.04.

For example this code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    g_print("gst_init...\n");
    gst_init(NULL, NULL);
    sleep(10);

    for (int pp = 0; pp < 10; pp++) {
        g_print("Iter #%d \n",pp);
        GstElement *pipeline;
        GError* err = NULL;

        pipeline = gst_parse_launch(
            " filesrc location=/media/datos/video12.mp4 "
            " ! qtdemux ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! fakesink name=appsink",
            &err);

        if (err) {
            g_printerr(err->message);
            g_error_free(err);
            return -1;
        }
        gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

        sleep(5);

        gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
        gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(pipeline));
        sleep(5);
    }

    gst_deinit();
    g_print("gst_deinit...\n");
    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `GST_DEBUG` environment variable to enable refcount debugging: `GST_DEBUG=GST_REFCOUNTING:5`

Comment: Thanks you. I tried, but I have a lot of information I do not understand. Maybe there is some document with more information about this. I read this: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html